# Remove last character/line

Tags: java, swing

I have a snippet of code that prints text from a file to a JTextArea called textArea.

Unfortunately the method I'm using goes line by line (not ideal) and so I have to append each line with a \n

This is fine for now but a new line is created at the end.

The code I have is as follows:

```
class menuOpen implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        try {
            File filePath = new File("c:\\test.txt");
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
            String displayText;

            while ((displayText = br.readLine()) != null) {
                textArea.append(displayText + "\n");
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me get rid of that last line?

Answer (score 6):

how about:

```
text.substring(0,text.lastIndexOf('\n'));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(...)
FileReader r= new FileReader(filePath);
StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder();
int n=0;
char array[]=new char[1024];
while((n=r.read(array))!=-1) b.append(array,0,n);
r.close();
String content=b.toString();
textArea.setText(content.substring(0,content.lengt()-1);
(...)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another idea:

```
boolean firstLine = true;
while ((displayText = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (firstLine) {
        firstLine = false;
    } else {
        textArea.append("\n");
    }
    textArea.append(displayText);
}
```

The idea is to append a line break **before** the new line to display, except for the first line of the file.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to not use `BufferedReader.readLine()`.  For example:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
char[] buf = new char[4096];
for (int count = in.read(buf); count != -1; count = in.read(buf)) {
    textArea.append(new String(buf, 0, count));
}
```

**EDIT**

I should have seen this before, but a much better way is to let the JTextArea read the file:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
textArea.read(in, null);
```

This will still read in the newline at the end, but it will normalize all the line endings in your text (see the [javadocs for `DefaultEditorKit`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html) for an explanation of how line endings are handled). So you can get rid of the trailing newline with something like this:

```
// line endings are normalized, will always be "\n" regardless of platform
if (textArea.getText().endsWith("\n")) {
    Document doc = ta.getDocument();
    doc.remove(doc.getLength() - 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if (textArea.length > 0) textArea.Text = textArea.Text.Substring(0 ,textArea.Text.Length - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want a newline *between* two lines, not *after each* line.  This means you should have at least two lines:

```
if (d = br.readLine()) != null ) {
    textArea.append(displayText);
    while (d = br.readLine()) != null ) {
        textArea.append( "\n" + displayText);
    }
}
```

Of course, it looks more complex.  That's because 'between' *is* more complex than 'after'.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop:

```
while ((displayText = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (textArea.length() > 0)
        textArea.append("\n");
    textArea.append(displayText);
}
```

i.e. if there is already some text in your textarea, insert a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite easy.. You just need to tweak your code a bit.

```
String displayText = br.readLine(); 
textArea.append(displayText);
while ((displayText = br.readLine()) != null) {
    textArea.append("\n" + displayText);
}
```

I believe this code produce your desired function at minimum cost.